# Perform SSH remote cmd exec on multiple local servers from input (sshpass?)

Tags: linux, networking, bash, ssh, shell

I am currently looking for a solution for executing remote commands on multiple local servers from an input file containing the 'user : password' in the following format:

```
jboss5:manager:192.168.1.101
database1:db01:192.168.20.6
server8:localnet:192.168.31.83
x:z:192.168.1.151
test:mynet:192.168.35.44
.... and others
```

Some commands I wish to execute remotely:

```
cd $HOME; ./start_script.sh; wget 192.168.1.110/monitor.sh; chmod +x monitor.sh; ./monitor.sh
```

I know there is a utility called "sshpass" but not sure how I could apply this utility for my needs.

I am open to any ideas in order to fulfill my need, any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hi, since you are looking into executing remote commands on multiple servers, you might be interested in Rex (over at https://www.rexify.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using password authentication I recommend you to use public key authentication, it is much stronger than plain password and you don't need then `sshpass`. Just create private keys without passwords and use `ssh`'s option `-i`, but if you still wish to use passwords, below is solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

hosts='
jboss5:manager:192.168.1.101
database1:db01:192.168.20.6
server8:localnet:192.168.31.83
x:z:192.168.1.151
test:mynet:192.168.35.44
'

for acct in ${hosts}; do
  user=$(echo "${acct}" | awk -F: '{print $1}')
  pass=$(echo "${acct}" | awk -F: '{print $2}')
  host=$(echo "${acct}" | awk -F: '{print $3}')

  sshpass -p "${pass}" ssh "${user}@${host}" \
    'cd $HOME; ./start_script.sh; wget 192.168.1.110/monitor.sh; chmod +x monitor.sh; ./monitor.sh'
done
```

Comment: This is awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for taking the time to write it down, very appreciated :)

Comment: @JohnDoe Glad to help. Consider in a future switch to public key authentication or at least use some anti-brute force solution like `fail2ban` on the servers and non default SSH port(22), it really dangerous to use plain passwords if servers exposed to the wild internet.